# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse error: Unable to parse Date format

Tags: java, android, date

I need to format following date fomat

```
 timeBooked: "2015-05-20T02:08:00.000Z",
 ExpiryTime: "2015-05-20T04:08:00.000Z",
```

My code follows to format the date:

```
try {
     Date currentDate = new Date(timeBooked);
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ZZ", Locale.ENGLISH);
     Log.e(TAG, "formatted time string: " + sdf.format(currentDate.getTime()));

     Log.e(TAG, "date string:=" + currentDate.getDate());
} catch (Exception e) {
         Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
         e.printStackTrace();
}
```

While running this code getting **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse error:2015-05-20T02:08:00.000Z**.

Comment: Isn't your format String really "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"

Comment: I will try this...And let you know

Answer (score 1):

Your format String is incorrect. It should be `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"`.

Then to get your date correctly you should use:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH);
// Set time zone to UTC since 'Z' at end of String specifies it.
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); 
// The parsed date will be offset from UTC in device's current TimeZone.
Date currentDate = sdf.parse(timeBooked);
```

Comment: This Answer is incorrect. Putting the single-quote marks around the `Z` means "expect to see this character, ignore it, but tell me if it is not present". You would be ignoring crucial information, the [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). If the value is indeed a "Z", it means "Zulu" which means an offset of 0, at UTC. But other valid offset values such as `-07:00` will throw an exception as if the input were invalid when in fact it would be valid.

Comment: @BasilBourque Good catch. I forgot to set the `TimeZone` on the formatter. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Date constructor taking a string is deprecated: see http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#Date(java.lang.String). It won't accept a custom date format; only a pre-defined set of formats are allowed.

Once you get your DateFormat string correct (I think "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" should work) you can call sdf.parse(timeBooked) to get a valid Date.

Answer (score 0):

## `Z` Has Meaning

Both of the previous Answers tell you to expect-and-ignore the `Z` character, by surrounding with single quotes in the coded parsing pattern. **Bad advice.** You would be ignoring valuable data, and would be rejecting valid alternative inputs such as `2015-05-20T02:08:00.000+05:30`. The pattern code `Z` means "any valid [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset)". Adding the single quotes for `'Z'` says "expect an uppercase Z to appear here, ignore any meaning it may have, and throw an exception if the Z is missing".

## Joda-Time

You are using the old date-time classes bundled with early versions of Java. Those classes have proven to be troublesome, flawed in both design and implementation. Avoid them. In current Android, add the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library to your project. In Java 8 and later, use the java.time framework that was inspired by Joda-Time.

Your string inputs are in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard format. Both Joda-Time and java.time use ISO 8601 as their defaults when parsing/generating textual representations of date-time values. So you these classes can directly parse such strings without you needing to specify any coded parsing patterns.

The following code creates a date-time assigned an offset-from-UTC of 0, which is what the `Z` (for `Zulu`) means.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse( "2015-05-20T02:08:00.000Z" );
```

Using a constructor has a different meaning. The following code parses the value with an offset of zero but then adjusts the results into your JVM’s current default time zone.

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "2015-05-20T02:08:00.000Z" ) );
```

I suggest you always explicitly assign your desired/expected time zone.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimezone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTime dateTime_Europe_Paris = dateTime.withZone( zone );
```

If you really need a java.util.Date, convert after doing your parsing and business logic with Joda-Time.

```
java.util.Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```

Search StackOverflow for *many* more Questions and Answers with example code for Joda-Time.